# Python list comprehension: populating each inner-list with two variables

Tags: python

This works for creating the output [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]:

```
[[k%3 for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]
```

This works for creating the output [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]:

```
[[j for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]
```

Now, since my goal was to get output that looks like this: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

I tried the following, but I got an error:

```
[[j,k%3 for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]
```

The error is:

[[j,k%3 for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What's the output you're expecting? You could use parentheses to disambiguate the tuple, but I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was hoping to have each inner list be a list of two integers. The whole thing would look like this: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

Comment: Before creating large comprehensions you should always remember that one of the basic principles of Python is "Readability counts.".

Comment: Well then the syntax is only half of your problem, maybe you want `[j if i == 0 else k % 3 for ...]` if you insist on a list comprehension, but why not just `[j, k % 3]`?

Comment: @ jonrsharpe Great! That worked. Thanks! Just out of curiosity, would you explain the syntax is only half the problem.

Comment: Because, as Jay's answer shows, fixing the syntax of your attempt doesn't actually give the output you want. This is why a full [mcve] is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the expected result is

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

imo you simply need

```
[[i, k] for i in range(3) for k in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create it as a tuple:

```
[[(j,k%3) for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]
```

Output will be like below:

```
>>> [[(j,k%3) for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]
[[(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(0, 1), (0, 1)], [(0, 2), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 0)], [(1, 1), (1, 1)], [(1, 2), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (2, 0)], [(2, 1), (2, 1)], [(2, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

---

EDIT:

Expected Output Published by OP:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]
```

Code to achieve this:

```
  [[j,k] for j in range(3)  for k in range(3)]
```